# Is there a way to make (x mod p) mod q = x mod q possible?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to restrict $p$ and $q$ ($p, q \in primes$) in such a way that $(x$ mod $p)$ mod $q \equiv x$ mod $q$ always holds?

I actually need a looser condition:

**I need that if $x \equiv 0$ mod $q$, then $x \equiv 0$ mod $p$ mod $q$.**

Is the above mentioned condition (in bold) possible?

Comment: I think the third isomorphism theorem would be useful here.

Comment: If $q$ divides $p$, you should be good

Comment: @D_S Can third isomorphism theorem be useful in deciding the kind of primes that possess this property?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Is it possible if both p and q are primes?

Comment: I do not think this is possible just for prime numbers

Comment: No, because if p < x < q then $(x \mod p) \mod q \not \equiv x \mod q$.

Comment: BTW (x mod p) as a number rather than an equivalence class is an abuse of definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \equiv 0 \mod q$, we have $x = kq$.

Now, for all integer $k$, we must have that $(kq \bmod p) \equiv 0 \mod q$.

However, as $q$ and $p$  are coprime $(kq \bmod p)$ takes on all residues $[0, p-1]$, so we see this is impossible.

Comment: $k$ and $p$ could have a common divisor.

Comment: @Χpẘ That doesn't matter. $k < p$ is sufficient to get all residues and since $p$ is prime that means no common divisor.

Comment: What if $x=npq$ (as suggested in another answer)?

Comment: @Χpẘ The question isn't about finding an $x$ that works. but that for certain $p, q$ all $x$ work.